# Where is Dekuuna?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just go the mission "Dekuuna: Elcor Extraction" and I need to go to the planet Dekuuna. The mission does not specify where I should go to find this planet and I don't see any indication anywhere on the galaxy map of where I should go. So, what mass relay and system should I go to in order to find Dekuuna?

Comment: Problem is: If you already scanned Dekuuna for the "Dekuuna: Code of the Ancients" quest, you might have scanned Oltan too and already picked up the Elcor Army without having the quest. So just return to the quest giver and end the mission like Gh0sT already said.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Elcor homeworld of Dekunna is in the Silean Nebula, in the Phontes system.  I see that you've found Oltan - Oltan is actually a satellite of Dekuuna, so it should be right there.

If you found the Elcor asset there, you're in the right place - the ships you're looking for are apparently on Oltan, actually.  (It's even possible you already found this one without realizing it, maybe)

[More at the Mass Effect wiki.](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Dekuuna:_Elcor_Extraction)

Answer (score 8):

The planet with the survivors you're looking is named *Oltan*. *Oltan* is in the *Phontes System* which, in turn, is in the *Silean Nebula*. As for where *Dekuuna* is, it's the big planet right next door to *Oltan*.

Once you scan *Oltan* and pick up the *Elcor Flotilla*, just head back to the *Citadel Embassies* and talk to the *Elcor Ambassador* again to finish the quest.

Comment: This is false. When I go to that planet there is no option to land or scan. I know I found an Elcor asset there, but that is not the same as this mission. Anyway, the mission says that the planet is named Dekuuna, as my question says.

Comment: True, but you actually need to head to Oltan, not Dekuuna. Regardless, I've updated the answer.

Comment: OK, I understand now. I changed my vote.

Answer (score 3):

*Dekuuna* is located in the *Phontes System* in the *Silean Nebula*. BUT if you have already completed "Dekuuna: Code of the Ancients" nothing happens when you scan it (it seems to be a bug). In that case just speak to the quest giver to complete the mission.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Silean Nebula (it might not originally show up on the galaxy map) and then to the Phontes system (there is an artefact on Dekuuna and a flotilla on its moon).

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Thank you for contributing, but your answer does not add anything to the existing answers. We would prefer that you no do this, as answers like this add noise without helping anyone.